# Pandas - Explode multiple columns in pandas and assign value based on the exploded column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**Reproducible example**:

```
ex = [{"explode1": ["a", "e", "i"], "word": "US_12", "explode2": []}, 
      {"explode1": [], "word": "US_34", "explode2": ["a", "e", "i"]}, 
      {"explode1": ["a", "e", "i"], "word": "US_56", "explode2": ["o", "u"]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(ex)
```

**Gives you**

```
        explode1   word   explode2
    0  [a, e, i]  US_12         []
    1         []  US_34  [a, e, i]
    2  [a, e, i]  US_56     [o, u]
```

You can assume there is also an `explode3` and an `explode4` column (excluded for the sake of brevity)

**Intended Result DataFrame**:

```
   exploded_alphabet   word    exploded_type
0                  a  US_12    explode1
1                  e  US_12    explode1
2                  i  US_12    explode1
3                  a  US_34    explode2
4                  e  US_34    explode2
5                  i  US_34    explode2
6                  a  US_54    explode1
7                  e  US_54    explode1
8                  i  US_54    explode1
9                  o  US_34    explode2
10                 u  US_34    explode2
```

The solution must be reproducible with 4 columns not just 2 mentioned above (I haven't included in my example `explode3` and `explode4` for the same of brevity)

So total number of rows will be equal to number of elements in all of the lists in `explode1`, `explode2`, `explode3` and `explode4` flattened.

**My efforts**:

Honestly, I'm thinking there must be a shorter Pythonic way rather than exploding each one individually and then exploding those that have multiple types.

```
df = df.explode("explode1")
df = df.explode("explode2")
```

The above is incorrect. Since this does not explode the rows simultaneously. It creates duplicates if list is non empty in multiple explosion columns.

---

The other one is the non-pythonic way where you iterate row wise and create and assign a new column - this is lengthy and easy to do. But this problem has probably been solved in a different way.

---

**How is my question different from other "explode multiple columns" question?**:

1. Exploding them separately. Every element in those columns creates a new row (This is probably already there on SO)
2. Assign the value in the `exploded_type` - Not sure if this has been solved on SO in conjunction to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before `explode` for unpivot and then remove rows with missing values (from empty lists):

```
df = (df.melt('word', value_name='exploded_alphabet', var_name='exploded_type')
        .explode("exploded_alphabet")
        .dropna(subset=['exploded_alphabet'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
     word exploded_type exploded_alphabet
0   US_12      explode1                 a
1   US_12      explode1                 e
2   US_12      explode1                 i
3   US_56      explode1                 a
4   US_56      explode1                 e
5   US_56      explode1                 i
6   US_34      explode2                 a
7   US_34      explode2                 e
8   US_34      explode2                 i
9   US_56      explode2                 o
10  US_56      explode2                 u
```

Answer (score 3):

you can `stack` and then `explode`:

```
result = df.set_index('word').stack().explode().dropna().reset_index(
    name='exploded_alphabet').rename(columns={'level_1': 'exploded_type'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
     word exploded_type exploded_alphabet
0   US_12      explode1                 a
1   US_12      explode1                 e
2   US_12      explode1                 i
3   US_34      explode2                 a
4   US_34      explode2                 e
5   US_34      explode2                 i
6   US_56      explode1                 a
7   US_56      explode1                 e
8   US_56      explode1                 i
9   US_56      explode2                 o
10  US_56      explode2                 u
```

**PERFORMANCE:**

```
for _ in range(20):
    df = df.append(df)
    
len(df) # 3145728

%%timeit 
(
    df.set_index('word')
    .stack().
    explode().
    dropna().
    reset_index(name='exploded_alphabet').
    rename(columns={'level_1': 'exploded_type'})
)

4.77 s ± 62.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
(
     df.melt('word', value_name='exploded_alphabet', var_name='exploded_type')
        .explode("exploded_alphabet")
        .dropna(subset=['exploded_alphabet'])
)
6.68 s ± 224 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
explode_columns = ['explode1', 'explode2']
pd.melt(
    frame=df,
    id_vars='word',
    value_vars=explode_columns,
    var_name='exploded_type',
    value_name='exploded_alphabet'
).explode('exploded_alphabet').dropna()

7.17 s ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: `NOTE: Not tested for large dataframes.` - hmmm, so then what is reason of timings for small data?

Comment: Hmmm... make sense!  Let me test for large dataframes, and add the results. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.melt` to stack the columns then explode it.

```py
explode_columns = ['explode1', 'explode2']
pd.melt(
    frame=df,
    id_vars='word',
    value_vars=explode_columns,
    var_name='exploded_type',
    value_name='exploded_alphabet'
).explode('exploded_alphabet').dropna()
```

It doesn't retain the same order as above but the rows are the same.